# Cannot call commit when using distributed transactions (EJB, Spring, Hibernate and Weblogic)

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, distributed

I'm creating an EJB in an existent application (running in weblogic 12), to call a method in a Spring component, that calls a DAO annotated as @Transactional to modify a record in the database. The problem is that after call the DAO method I received the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC commit failed
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:661)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:475)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:270)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at org.newton.imp.storage.dao.AresDaoImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f33ba225.saveAresStatus(<generated>)
    at org.newton.imp.storage.managers.ares.AresManagerImpl.uploadDocument(AresManagerImpl.java:166)
    at org.newton.imp.storage.managers.ares.AresManagerImpl.registerDocument(AresManagerImpl.java:326)
    at org.newton.imp.storage.managers.ares.AresManagerImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$d04be4e1.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:627)
    at org.newton.imp.storage.managers.ares.AresManagerImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$ec954055.registerDocument(<generated>)
    at org.newton.business.ejb.NewtonAresManagerBean.registerDocument(NewtonAresManagerBean.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext.proceed(MethodInvocationInvocationContext.java:103)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.JeeInterceptorInterceptor.invoke(JeeInterceptorInterceptor.java:115)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at $Proxy707.registerDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.newton.business.ejb.NewtonAresManagerBean_po5cm8_NewtonAresManagerRemoteImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:32)
    at org.newton.business.ejb.NewtonAresManagerBean_po5cm8_NewtonAresManagerRemoteImpl.registerDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.newton.business.ejb.NewtonAresManagerBean_po5cm8_NewtonAresManagerRemoteImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.ServerRequest.sendReceive(ServerRequest.java:201)
    at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:461)
    at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:272)
    at org.newton.business.ejb.NewtonAresManagerBean_po5cm8_NewtonAresManagerRemoteImpl_1211_WLStub.registerDocument(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.invoke(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:84)
    ... 21 more

    Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC commit failed
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:161)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:657)
        ... 64 more

    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot call commit when using distributed transactions
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTAConnection.commit(JTAConnection.java:365)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commitAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:170)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:146)
        ... 65 more
```

My configuration/ classes are:

EJB:

```
@Stateless(name = "NewtonAresManagerBean", mappedName = "NewtonAresManagerRemote")
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
public class NewtonAresManagerBean implements NewtonAresManagerRemote {   
    protected static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NewtonAresManagerBean.class);

    @Autowired
    private AresManager aresManager;


    @Override
    public String registerDocument(final FileStorage fileStorage, final ProjectInformationTO project, final AresTypes aresType, final Long reportingPeriod, final AresProcessingType processingType) throws CommonNewtonException, NoInternalEntityFoundException, NoExternalEntityFoundException {       

        Object status = aresManager.registerDocument(aresType, fileStorage, project, reportingPeriod, null, null, null, processingType);
    }
}
```

Spring component:

```
@Component("aresManager")
public class AresManagerImpl implements AresManager {
     @Override
    public Object registerDocument(final AresTypes aresType, final FileStorage fileStore, final ProjectInformationTO projectInformation,
            final Integer periodNumber, final Long submissionId, final String participantId, final Long participantNumber,
            final AresProcessingType aresProcessingType)
            throws CommonBusinessException {

    Object status = new Status();
    final Object uploadBean = uploadDocument(aresType, status, fileStore);
        return uploadBean;
    }


    @Override
    public Object uploadDocument(final AresTypes aresType, final AresStatus status, final FileStorage fileStore) {
        try {
            final Object responseBean = getCommonHelper().uploadFile(aresType, fileStore);

            getCommonHelper().getAresDao().saveAresStatus(status);

            return responseBean;
        } catch (final Exception e) {            
        } 
        return null;
    }
}
```

DAO:

```
@Repository("aresDao")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class AresDaoImpl implements AresDao {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("mySessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory mySessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void saveAresStatus(final AresStatus status) {
        try {
            mySessionFactory.getSession().saveOrUpdate(status) 
        } catch (final Exception e) {
        }

    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd"
    default-autowire="byName">

    <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->

    <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="fpX_business_datasource">

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate

                hibernate.generate_statistics=true

                hibernate.show_sql=false
                hibernate.format_sql=true
                hibernate.use_sql_comments=false

                hibernate.max_fetch_depth=1

                hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session=false

                hibernate.use_identifier_rollback=true

                hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=5

                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
        hibernate.transaction.factory_class=org.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
                hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
                hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=false
                hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=false
                hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts=false
            </value>
        </property>        
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebLogicJtaTransactionManager">
        <property name="transactionManagerName" value="javax.transaction.TransactionManager" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>
</beans>
```

I'll really appreciate if someone can give a clue on how to solve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem was that Spring was using the HibernateTransactionManager instead of WebLogicJtaTransactionManager, because there was another file defining other transaction manager. Once it was changed to have only one file and one transaction manager the exception dissappear.